# D3: center a map feature using correct latitude and longitude, without rotation?

Tags: javascript, latitude-longitude, d3

The following is a map of Chicago which I've created in D3.js, and the JS code to render it.

I had a very hard time centering Chicago within my viewfinder (the white box).  After much trial and error, I was finally able to make it work, with the long/lat of `[8.25, 41.88205]` and a rotation of `[92.35, .5, -4]`, using the Albers projection.  This seems weird to me, since the long/lat of Chicago *should* be `[87.627815, 41.88205]`.

So, my questions are: what is up with the `8.25` longitude?  Why doesn't D3 center Chicago on my screen simply with the long/lat of `[87.627815, 41.88205]`?  And why do I need to apply the rotation at all?

BTW, the `community_areas_sm.geojson` file comes off the [City of Chicago website](https://data.cityofchicago.org/browse?tags=shapefiles), and contains correct long/lat values.

[image: D3 map of Chicago]

```
<script>
var width = 600,
    height = 750

var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)

var map = d3.json(
    "/static/data/community_areas_sm.geojson", function(error, map) {
        if (error) return console.error(error)

        var proj = d3.geo.albers()
            .center([8.25, 41.88205])
            .parallels([40, 45])
            .scale(105000)
            .rotate([92.35, .5, -4])
            .translate([width / 2, height / 2])

        svg.selectAll("path")
            .data(map.features)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(proj))
        }
    )
</script>
```

Comment: What happens if you use -87.6 and no rotation? Software often wants negative longitudes in the western hemisphere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rotation is necessary because [d3.geo.albers](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#albers) defaults to centering on the [middle of the US](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3734308) (`center` and `rotate` are used in that block but they match the [defaults](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#albers)).

I haven't seen a clear explanation of this in the d3 docs but here's what I've pieced together using d3.geo for various things:  use `rotate` to spin the globe to your area of interest. Most of the time (all the time?) this means changing longitude only. The longitude sent to `rotate` should be the longitude you want to be the center of your map AKA the [central meridian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Notable_lines). After `rotate`, you can shift the center of your map in either direction but it's common to specify longitude as 0 (since your map is already where you want it in the x direction) and use latitude to shift your map's center north or south. You can see this in the [Let's Make a Map](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) tutorial.

As for the latitude of 8.25, I think that's getting the map back to Chicago after rotating in three directions (`[92.35, .5, -4]`). I don't know enough to give a mathematical explanation but that's my guess.

If you create your projection like so:

```
var proj = d3.geo.albers()
  .center([0, 41.83])
  .rotate([87.65, 0])
  .parallels([40, 45])
  .scale(30000)
  .translate([w / 2, h / 2])
```

you'll be [centered on Chicago](http://bl.ocks.org/swingley/390b394f8b449d83f255).